# mongo db aggregation/mapreduce

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i am trying to extract uniq keys + all uniq values from an object of my mongo-documents.

lets say i have document structure like:

```
{
    "userId": "1234",
    "formFields": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
    }
},
{
    "userId": "1234",
    "formFields": {
        "field3": "value3",
        "field1": "value1-edited"
    }
},
{
    "userId": "1234",
    "formFields": {
        "field3": "value3",
        "field1": "value1-edited"
    }
}
```

i want to aggregate all documents from user "1234"  to get the distinct values of "formFields"

result should look something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "formFields": {
        "field1": [
            "value1",
            "value1-edited"
        ],
        "field2": [
            "value2"
        ],
        "field3": [
            "field3"
        ],
        "field4": [
            "field4"
        ]
    }
}
```

they keys in the formFields are dynamic.
i tried arround with aggregate, and mapreduce but haven't found any working sample that can be used as a basis.

anyone can answer this?

THANKS

regards
helmut

Comment: What code did you try with the aggregation framework?

Comment: i just tried to find a good sample to start off one was

some of them are here: https://gist.github.com/hjanuschka/6fe70ca46c8b681a48d8

actually i am on point zero - just started using mongodb - and i have no clue where to go with this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have dynamic keys that you don't know beforehand, you would need to get a list of those fields so that you can use them in your aggregation pipeline. One way to get that list is through mapReduce. The following demonstrates this approach. In the Map-Reduce operation, an array of keys in the `formFields` subdocument is generated to an output collection "uploads_keys" and then used to produce the aggregation pipeline expressions:

```
var mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "uploads",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this.formFields) { emit(key, null); }
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { 
        return null  
    }, 
    "out": "uploads" + "_keys"
});

var groupKeys = {},
    projectKeys = { "formFields": {} };
db[mr.result].distinct("_id").forEach(function (key){    
    groupKeys[key] = { "$push": "$formFields." + key };
    projectKeys["formFields"][key] = "$" + key
});

groupKeys["_id"] = "$userId";

> printjson(groupKeys);
{
        "field1" : {
                "$push" : "$formFields.field1"
        },
        "field2" : {
                "$push" : "$formFields.field2"
        },
        "field3" : {
                "$push" : "$formFields.field3"
        },
        "_id" : "$userId"
}
> printjson(projectKeys);
{
        "formFields" : {
                "field1" : "$field1",
                "field2" : "$field2",
                "field3" : "$field3"
        }
}
```

You can then use those variables in your aggregation pipeline:

```
db.uploads.aggregate([
    { "$group": groupKeys },
    { "$project": projectKeys }
])
```

Comment: ok this is actually a good starting point - does what i want it to do!
BUT: they keys are hardcoded - is there a variation of this piece with dynamic keys? - and $push does not seem to be uniqe

Comment: I've updated my answer with an approach that you could take to generate the list of dynamic keys.

Comment: this is like 99.9% the solution i am looking for - many thx - any chance to kick out duplicate values?

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible indeed. Just use **`$addToSet`** instead of the **`$push`** operator within the **`$group`** pipeline. Also, it would be very helpful if you could read [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: THX - addToSet did it! now its a 100%  perfect - many thx, and i already confirmed your question, just wanted to wait if i get a reply for the uniqe question.